# Is this a floor framing system? what is the difference between joist splices and floor joists?

Tags: flooring, floor

I googled "floor framing" and got lots of results. The following (img_1) is the simpler one.

[image]

According to the anotations in the image, there are 7 joists, 2 bearers, 6 stumps, right?

Consider the following image (img_2), is this another floor framing system?

[image]

what is the difference between joist splices and floor joists?

Answer (score 5):

Joists are just that, members that carry the sub-flooring or ceiling. A joist splicing occurs where the length of span of the floor is longer than the joists are capable of supporting so a beam or "girder" is placed under the ends of the joists. Joists from either side of the support beam overhang the beam some and overlap with their companion coming from the other side. This picture shows the concept:

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://www.awc.org/pdf/codes-standards/publications/wcd/AWC-WCD1-ConventionalWoodFrame-ViewOnly-0107.pdf)*</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is my understanding (there are 7 joists, 2 bearers, 6 stumps) about img_1 right?

Comment: @zghqh - Yeah. Seems like we both count up the items in the diagram the same.

Comment: Thank you! Your example get me a better understanding. There are 4 joists in total in your example, 2 joists and their splicing, is my understanding right?

Comment: @zghqh the "splice" is the area of overlap between the two joists that meet over the girder. Yes, in this image, there are 4 joists and 2 splices. I would, however, refer to each spliced pair as _a_ joist. Yes, they're offset, but they more-or-less work together as one.